# How to Handle the empty sys.argv[1], if the value is available it shuld print the value if not it shuld print blank

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am writing a script to get the Build related changes in azure devops and it expects argument which is added in the azure deployment file to run the script. That program works as expected, but I want to change it so that if the Build is triggered by PR it should show the PR source branch and PR target branch  values and if the Build is triggered by the branch it should show the Source branch only.

Running script with arguments as below in deployment

- `script: python3 $(Python_file.secureFilePath) $(System.AccessToken) $(Build.Repository.Name) $(Build.DefinitionName) $(Build.BuildNumber) "$(Build.SourceBranchName)""$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)" "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"`

My Previous code is some thing like this below
import

`sys`
`pat = sys.argv[1]`

`repo_name = sys.argv[2]`

`pipeline_name = sys.argv[3]`

`build_number = sys.argv[4]`

`Source_Branch = sys.argv[5]`

`PR_Source_Branch = sys.argv[6]`

`PR_Target_Branch = sys.argv[7]`

Am doing changes some thing like this below which is not working please let me know how it should be

import sys

`Source_Branch =`

`{`

`def get_arg(Source_Branch):`

`try:`
`sys.argv[5]`

`except sysargvError:`

`return ''`

`else:`
`return sys.argv[5]`

`}`

`PR_Source_Branch =`

`{`

`def get_arg(PR_Source_Branch):`

`try:`
`sys.argv[6]`

`except sysargvError:`

`return ''`

`else:`

`return sys.argv[6]`

`}`

`PR_Target_Branch =`

`{`

`def get_arg(PR_Target_Branch):`

`try:`
`sys.argv[7]`

`except sysargvError:`

`return ''`

`else:`
`return sys.argv[7]`

`}`

expected :

if PR is raised for source Branch to target Branch after merge it will trigger the Build then it should pick up
`PR_Source_Branch = sys.argv[6]`

`PR_Target_Branch = sys.argv[7]`

if the Build was run from Branch (Manually) then it should pick up as below because it will not have the source and target Branch's as it was not triggered by PR it will not have that values

`Source_Branch = sys.argv[5]`

Comment: Please format your code as one block. The newlines in-between make it very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Python "try" doesn't have an "else" clause. Also this is not the error you need to catch. Perhaps something like this:

```
Source_Branch = {
  def get_arg(Source_Branch):
    try: 
      return sys.argv[5]
    except IndexError:
      return '' 
}
```